# AJAX / Jquery XML parse

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery, xml-parsing

I try parsing the following type of XML (data from **getMembers.php**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<members>
   <id>3422345</id>
   <name>Bill Gates</name>
   <id>232311</id>
   <name>Bob Barker</name>
</members>
```

And I use the code below to parse it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getMembers.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('members').each(function(){
                    var name = $(this).find("name").text()
                    alert(name);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

No error but I get both names at the same time.

Like:

> Bill GatesBob Barker <--first loop>

Instead of

> Bill Gates <--first loop>
>
> Bob Barker <--second loop>

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is that a typo : <memebers> ?

Comment: Oops sorry about that. It's been corrected.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you iterate over members, not names:

```
success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('members').each(function(){
                    $(this).find("name").each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).text();
                        alert(name);
                    });
                });
            }
```

Or maybe your XML should looks like:

```
<members>
   <id>3422345</id>
   <name>Bill Gates</name>
</members>
<members>
   <id>232311</id>
   <name>Bob Barker</name>
</members>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks fmgp! :o)

Comment: i also recommend to use the following valid xml format as seen in the answer from user2780947:


<members>
  <member>
    <id>123</id>
    <name>First Last</name>
  </member>
  <member>
    <id>124</id>
    <name>Bill Gates</name>
  </member>
</members>

Answer (score 2):

This way show names:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getMembers.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('name').each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).text();
                        alert(name);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering if you successfully parsed that XML data.

The valid XML format is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<members>
  <member>
   <id>3422345</id>
   <name>Bill Gates</name>
  </member>
  <member>
   <id>232311</id>
   <name>Bob Barker</name>
 </member>
</members>
```