# Jquery issue while reading in xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have a issue when i read a xml File with jquery. This is my call to find the xml and the section. It works untill here

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:"../quiz.xml",
    dataType: "xml"}).always(function(xml) {

    // level in xml finden und anschließend question in level finden  
    var level = $(xml).find("level"+ sessionStorage.getItem('level'));
var question = $(level).find("question");
var frage = $(question[number]).find('frage');

$('.questions').html(frage);
```

This is what stand in the xml file. The problem is that it output  as sting and not as html-Tag. Did i forot something?

```
<frage>
Was sind <![CDATA[ < br />]]>  Versalien?
</frage>
```

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223865/ajax-jquery-xml-parse

Comment: the problem is the output. That he the <br /> is as string there and not as html tag

Comment: If it's literally `< br />`, then there is something wrong with the markup (the space between `<` and `br`). You'd have to fix that manually.