# Get the resulting text of the xmlhttp

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "https://url.org/pTest/isoe.asmx/echo?say=dsafd";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,   
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,   
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("Success: " + msg);
                    $("#contentHolder").text(msg);

                }, error: function() {
                    alert("Error!!");
                }
            });
        });
```

The result that is alerted in the success function looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://url.org">you said:dsafd        --&gt;SHA1:a6c9c8ffe4422e3ec4d46eac9ea552ff75c9d41b64add68a7b7ff8659a5b739e</string>
```

So I am basically just using `.../echo?say=something";` What I want to do, is to get the result of the: `/echo?say=dsafd";` So I want it to alert "dsafd" instead of the entire xml file. I tried using: `msg.responseText` and `msg.responseXML`, but these don't work. They are empty. How can I get the result of the echo?

Comment: remove `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` it is not used at all. You are mixing XMLHTTPRequest and jQuery AJAX which can get and parse XML for you - you can start by changing `dataType: "xml"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX / Jquery XML parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223865/ajax-jquery-xml-parse)

Comment: If I change the dataType to xml, I get an undefined on the returned data. For some reason, it must be html

Comment: the server needs to return valid xml with mime type  text/xml and not text/html too. Look in the console/network tab to see what it is